# Camera preview appears stretched

Tags: android, android-camera2

Im trying to use camera 2 with and AutoFitTextureView from the google sample.

Im setting it up like this

```
private void setUpCameraOutputs() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (manager != null) {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                if (characteristics.get(LENS_FACING) == LENS_FACING_FRONT) continue;

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

                if(map != null) {
                    // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                    List<Size> outputSizes = Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(sImageFormat));
                    Size largest = Collections.max(outputSizes, new CompareSizesByArea());
                    mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, sImageFormat, 8);
                    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could exceed the camera
                    // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                    // garbage capture data.
                    mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), largest);
                    //mPreviewSize = new Size(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight());
                    setAspectRatio2(mPreviewSize);
                    Logging.e(TAG, "WIDTH: " + mPreviewSize.getWidth() + " HEIGHT: " + mPreviewSize.getHeight());

                    mCameraId = cameraId;
                }
                //return;
            }
        }else{
            Logging.e(TAG,"No Manager");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setAspectRatio(){
    int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    } else {
        mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(),mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    }
}

private void setAspectRatio2(Size largest){
    float cameraAspectRatio = (float) largest.getHeight() / largest.getWidth();
    //Preparation
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int finalWidth = screenWidth;
    int finalHeight = screenHeight;
    int widthDifference = 0;
    int heightDifference = 0;
    float screenAspectRatio = (float) screenWidth / screenHeight;

    //Determines whether we crop width or crop height
    if (screenAspectRatio > cameraAspectRatio) { //Keep width crop height
        finalHeight = (int) (screenWidth / cameraAspectRatio);
        heightDifference = finalHeight - screenHeight;
    } else { //Keep height crop width
        finalWidth = (int) (screenHeight * cameraAspectRatio);
        widthDifference = finalWidth - screenWidth;
    }

    //Apply the result to the Preview
    LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mTextureView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = finalWidth;
    lp.height = finalHeight;
    //Below 2 lines are to center the preview, since cropping default occurs at the right and bottom
    lp.leftMargin = - (widthDifference / 2);
    lp.topMargin = - (heightDifference / 2);
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    double ratio = (double) h / w;
    for (Size option : choices) {
        double optionRatio = (double) option.getHeight() / option.getWidth();
        if (ratio == optionRatio) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }

    // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Logging.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[1];
    }
}
```

I've tried to set the aspect ratio with 2 different methods, but none of them seem to do what i need.
The preview takes all screen as i want, but camera preview always appear streeched, things look thiner.
I've tried a few sugestions from stackoverflow but still haven't got the perfect result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries which ease the use of CameraView.
You can have a look at [this one](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat) or [this one](https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android) for example.

Comment: I can't use a external lib, it's required by my superiors

Comment: You can still look at these libraries source code to adapt your own TextureView.